# Why are Elements of Byte Slices Returned as Ints in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, types, slice

On the go playground, this code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var a = []byte{ 0xff, 0xaa, 0x66, 0x33, 0x00 }

func main() {
    for b := range a {
        fmt.Printf("%T\n", b)
    }
}
```

prints

```
int
int
int
int
int
```

Why in the world wouldn't a slice of bytes give you bytes when you iterate through it (or at least uint8 or something)?

Here's the link to the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/V1uZZWWq-X.

Comment: Oh wait is it because `[]byte` is equivalent to `string` and iterating through a `string` should give you a `rune`?  This is mad confusing, why not limit that sort of behavior to the `string` type?

Comment: No, `for i := range thing` sets i to _indices_ into thing (unlike Python or such). `for i, b := range byteslice` would put the index in `i` and byte in `b`, and `for _, b := range byteslice` would just put the byte in `b`.

Comment: Oh gosh, I'm stupid, thanks a ton.  If you want to make that an answer i'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for i := range thing` sets `i` to indices into the thing (unlike Python or such). `for i, b := range byteslice` would put the *index* in `i` and byte in `b`, and `for _, b := range byteslice` would just put the byte in `b`.

[The spec on for statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) lays out all the different special cases related to `range` expressions (including strings, channels, and maps as well).

Answer (score 3):

It's not the slice/bytes/strings/runes causing the problem. It's your use of range. You're expecting to be looking at the current item but you're actually looking at the integer that represents the current index on each iteration of the loop.

To be clear, if your loops form is; `for i, v := range` then `i` is an int representing the current index while `v` is a block of temporary storage that the value at index `i` is assigned to. If you want only the values then your loop would be; `for _, v := range`. When you only have one identifier on the left it assigned the index, not the value.